# Anyone successfully installed zend server CE on amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: apache-2.2, zend-framework, amazon-ec2

Trying to install zend server CE (5.3) on the new release of amazon Linux AMI (2012.09).
Had no problem with the previous release (2012.03), but cannot get it to work this time around: Apache won't start.

I get the following error message:

```
Starting apachectl: httpd: Syntax error on line 351 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax   error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/zendserver_php.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/zend/lib/apache2/libphp5.so into server: /usr/local/zend/lib/apache2/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
```

[FAILED]

Any thoughts on what that means and what I should do?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe better luck on serverfault then here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christopher G. Stach II provided the following answer on a different forum:

That means that the binary distribution of zend, including the php5 module for Apache httpd, which you installed is probably not linked against the same version of Apache httpd or has some other incompatible build/configuration differences. You will probably either need to upgrade your Apache httpd, use an approved distribution, or build/find a compatible zend.